# Issue with Mocking in Testing: Endpoint Recalculates Value Instead of Using Mocked Return

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, fastapi

I'm relatively new to mocking in testing, and I'm encountering an issue with my testing approach. I have an endpoint in my FastAPI application that interacts with a memcache service:

```
@memcache_router.post(
    "/cache/item",
    tags=["Memcache"],
    description="Create Memcache item.",
    dependencies=[Depends(HasPermissions(["appAccess"]))],
)
async def post_memcache_items_by_id(cache_item: Annotated[str, Form(...)]):

    item_id = create_memcache_item(memcache_item=cache_item)

    return item_id
```

Alongside, I have a method to create a memcache item:

```
def create_memcache_item(memcache_item: str) -> str:

    milliseconds = str(round(time() * 1000))
    client = base.Client(("localhost", 11211))
    client.set(milliseconds, memcache_item)
    return milliseconds
```

To avoid issues caused by the absence of the memcache service in my testing pipeline, I'm attempting to use mocking. Below is my test implementation:

```
client = TestClient(app)
client.headers = token_headers()

class TestPostMemcacheItemById:
    def test_post_memcache_item_by_id_valid_data(self):
        """
        Test post Memcache Item By Id Endpoint with valid data
        """
        endpoint = f"{API_BASE_URL}/cache/item/"
        metadata = {"cache_item": "test"}
        milliseconds = str(round(time() * 1000))

        with patch("api.crud.memcached.create.create_memcache_item") as create_memcache_function:
            create_memcache_function.return_value = milliseconds

            response = client.post(endpoint, data=metadata)

        create_memcache_function.assert_called()
        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
        assert response.json() == milliseconds
```

What I expect is that the value returned by create_memcache_item should be constant during the test. However, it seems that the endpoint recalculates this value instead of using the mocked return value. What am I missing here? I've been unable to identify the issue.

Comment: Is `post_memcache_items_by_id` in `api.crud.memcached.create`, or is it somewhere else using something like `from api.crud.memcached.create import create_memcache_item`? If the latter, you are patching the wrong name.

Comment: I was doing a dummy mistake by mocking the whole function **create_memcache_item** , instead of mocking the part of **post_memcache_items_by_id** which contains this function. Thanks :)